# How to record USB webcam feed at acceptable FPS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a generic USB webcam connected to my Raspberry Pi 3B+. I am trying to record a video in at least 1280x720 resolution at 30fps, but currently I am unable to record even 640x480 above 25fps with this command:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 /home/pi/Desktop/out.avi`

When I run *v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext* command I receive the following response:

```
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 1.000s (1.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)"
```

I have tried many different combinations of the recording command but they all resulted in far lower FPS.

Comment: How are you determining the FPS?  Most video captures are using compression and only recording changes from one frame to next frame.  The video file has an ASCII header that you can see in Notepad which should indicate the frame size and compression mode.

Comment: When I said 25FPS I was going off the command line log during recording. I just checked the metadata with ffmpeg, I wasn't able to open the avi with my text editor, and it does say 30FPS. Yet, when I watch the video it is for sure way slower and choppy.

Comment: 30 FPS can be choppy depending on graphic mode, what else is running on machine, and speed of media that is being used to read video.  Try playing video back on a desktop PC to see if video is still choppy.

Comment: See following : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094139/choppy-video-under-ubuntu-but-not-windows